# Convert grayscale 2D numpy array to RGB image

Tags: python, image, numpy, rgb, grayscale

I have a Grayscale 'TIF' image which I've read as a numpy array which is 2D

The pixel intensities ranging from 17 to 317 in my 2D array.

I have two challenges

1. convert this 2D array into RGB image
2. scale the pixel intensities (between 17 to 317) to RGB values and show the Gray scale image as RGB color image

[image: greyscale img]

I unfortunately cannot use Opencv and Matplotlib as the end product on which I am working does not support these

Comment: Maybe you could share your TIF - use Dropbox or Google Drive if you can't upload it here. Do you want the result as PNG, or JPEG or something else? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You have shared an 8-bit PNG not the 16-bit TIF you said you have. Please upload your actual image, using Dropbox or Google Drive or some other service if Stack Overflow doesn't allow you to upload a TIF. Thank you.

Comment: Please say how you plan to read a TIF image without **OpenCV**. Do you have **PIL/Pillow** available? Or are you planning to use `tifffile`?

Comment: Access is denied for the Google Drive image.

Comment: Hello Marksetchell, i have uploaded the tif image to Google drive. Please find the link below. You can use imageJ software to visualize it. Otherwise in python        from PIL import Image , image.show() we can visualize the image. Thank you.        https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v_S5CnoCm9dp40XsJkeR8I7eBKUNVeUk/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I have updated the permission. you can visualize it now

Comment: Hello Mark Setchell, Yes you did answered my question and it worked forme.. Thanks a ton, I did reply to your answer. I am surprised , as its not seen here. Thanks a ton for  timely support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that there are 3 aspects to your question:

- creating a colormap, or LUT *"Lookup Table"*
- scaling your pixels to a standard range
- applying a colormap to an image without `matplotlib`.

---

So, to create a colormap, we need a list of 256 RGB values in which
we can lookup any greyscale value and find the colour we want to show it as. I understand you can't use `matplotlib` in production, but you can grab a colormap or two from there on some other machine and copy it to your production machine. So, let's do that. We'll take the `viridis` colormap:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

# Get 256 entries from "viridis" or any other Matplotlib colormap
colmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis', 256)

# Make a Numpy array of the 256 RGB values
# Each line corresponds to an RGB colour for a greyscale level
np.savetxt('cmap.csv', (colmap.colors[...,0:3]*255).astype(np.uint8), fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

If we look at that file `"cmap.csv"`, it has 256 lines and starts like this:

```
68,1,84
68,2,85
68,3,87
69,5,88
69,6,90
69,8,91
70,9,92
...
...
```

That means anywhere we see `0` in the greyscale image, we actually colour the pixel  `rgb(68,1,86)`. Anywhere we see `1` in the greyscale it maps to `rgb(68,2,85)`. Presumably you can copy that file to your production machine and you can choose any one of `Matplotlib`s [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

---

Regarding scaling, you have posted an 8-bit PNG image with a range of 0..117 rather than a 16-bit TIFF image with a range of 17..317, so that is not most helpful. Also, you have not said how you plan to read a TIFF on a system that doesn't have **OpenCV** or **matplotlib**, so I don't know whether you have **PIL/Pillow** or plan to use [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/).

Instead then, I will create a dummy 32x32 image with a range of 17..317 like this:

```
grey = np.random.randint(17,318, (32,32))
```

That looks like this:

```
array([[244,  75, 237, ..., 154, 190,  70],
       [286, 247, 158, ..., 150, 267, 124],
       [170, 305, 237, ..., 126, 111, 236],
       ...,
       [163, 292, 184, ...,  24, 253, 177],
       [314,  34,  36, ...,  87, 316, 182],
       [258, 153, 278, ..., 189,  57, 196]])
```

If we now want to scale that from the range 17..317 into the range 0..255, we can use:

```
rescaled = ((grey.astype(float) - grey.min())*255/(grey.max() - grey.min())).astype(np.uint8)
```

which gives us this:

```
array([[192,  49, 187, ..., 116, 147,  45],
       [228, 195, 119, ..., 113, 212,  90],
       [130, 244, 187, ...,  92,  79, 186],
       ...,
       [124, 233, 141, ...,   5, 200, 136],
       [252,  14,  16, ...,  59, 254, 140],
       [204, 115, 221, ..., 146,  34, 152]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

Looking up can be done by loading the CSV file containing our colourmap, and taking the corresponding elements from the colormap as indexed by your greyscale values in the range 0...255:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load image as greyscale and make into Numpy array
grey = np.array(Image.open('TdoGc.png').convert('L'))

# Load RGB LUT from CSV file
lut = np.loadtxt('cmap.csv', dtype=np.uint8, delimiter=',')

# Make output image, same height and width as grey image, but 3-channel RGB
result = np.zeros((*grey.shape,3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Take entries from RGB LUT according to greyscale values in image
np.take(lut, grey, axis=0, out=result)

# Save result
Image.fromarray(result).save('result.png')
```

[image]

If you scale your greyscale image to the full range after reading, using this line:

```
grey = ((grey.astype(float) - grey.min())*255/(grey.max() - grey.min())).astype(np.uint8)
```

You will get this:

[image]

---

If you want to visualise your colormap, change the line above that looks like this:

```
grey = np.array(Image.open('TdoGc.png').convert('L'))
```

into this so that it generates a gradient (ramp) image:

```
grey = np.repeat(np.arange(256,dtype=np.uint8).reshape(1,-1), 100, axis=0)
```

Then you can see your colourmap:

[image]

---

A quick hack to handle segmented linear colormaps that don't have a class variable enumerating the colours. So you can make the `cmap.csv` file from the `autumn` colourmap like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

# Get "autumn" colourmap
colmap = cm.get_cmap('autumn')

# Save 256 RGB entries as CSV - one for each of grey levels 0..255
np.savetxt('cmap.csv', np.array([colmap(i/255)[:3] for i in range(256)]) * 255, fmt="%d", delimiter=',')
```

[image]

Comment: Hello mark Setchell, Thanks a ton for your support. I have struggling with this for almost 2 weeks. Thanks again. I am able to get the color RGB image now. I have one question, if i want to make it autumn or other colormaps. it is not working. I am able to use only sequenctial colormaps. Kindly suggest a way to use other colormaps.

Comment: Thanks gain for helping me

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just chose the most popular (and default) colormap and didn't test the others because I never use `matplotlib` myself :-) I'll see if I can work out a way for the other ones like `autumn`.

Comment: I have added a bit at the bottom for the `autumn` colourmap. Please have another look.

Comment: Thank you. It is very useful.