# Getting "n" equally spaced RGB colors for "n" numbers, from a colormap

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have list of numbers, and want to assign a color for each of them from the `ylorbr` colormap in python.
If my intuition of a colormap is correct, its just a range of colors - so, `ylorbr` goes from yellow to orange to brown.

I just want to get `n` equally spaced tuples of colors from this colormap, starting from `0` (in this case, that is yellow).

This is the simple code I tried:

```
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
ylorbr = cm.get_cmap('YlOrBr', 8)
x = ylorbr(np.arange(0,1,0.1))

print(x)
```

When I try this, `x` is not a set of evenly spaced colors - in fact, colors are repeated. I also could not find other solutions for this - or there may be, but I am new to plotting.

I am new to plotting, but not new to python. Is there a reason, why getting a simple list of evenly spaced RGB from a given colormap is hard? I used "python sense" to do the above test, and actually expected an evenly spaced list of RGB tuples.

Can someone tell me how then a colormap works in python, and how to simply assign `n` sorted integers to `n` colors from a colormap in the shortest way possible?

Edit : I assumed here, that colormap is a discrete list of colors. I just want the first item , last item and every item at 1/n of that list of colors.

Edit2 : Based on Mark's comment below, I tried to access the list of colors of a map using the `.colors` attribute after `get_cmap`. But while it works when the colormap is `viridis`, it does not work when I set it to `YlOrBr` and I get the error : `'LinearSegmentedColormap' object has no attribute 'colors'`

Comment: It's late here so I'll take a look in the morning. In the meantime, this may help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/65477131/2836621

Comment: Strange.. this post suggests a way to access the list of colors of the map, by using "mapObject.colors" , but it works for the colormap "viridis" but not for "YlOrBr".

Comment: A colormap is not NECESSARILY
 a discrete list of colors.  In this case, it is a small set of line segments.  Colors are interpolated by formula as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked it to make a colormap with 8 entries.  It shouldn't be surprising that you get repeats when you ask for 10 results.

I can hear you screaming "arrgggh" from here.

Comment: Values are repeated even if I use a very large value there.

Comment: If I do `y = cm.get_cmap('YlOrBr',128)` / `y(np.arange(0,1,0.01)`, I get no duplicates.  How many are you asking for?

Comment: Argh, sorry, you're right. Accepted your answer... My actual list of values overflowed in length, so it had repeated values..

Comment: `cmap.resampled` below has no repeats,  or you could do `np.interp` straight up

Answer (score 0):

Colormaps have a `resampled` function, about what you want 
(but interpolating in RGB space can give you ugly colors, make color connoisseurs cry)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap  # ? in ipython

def cmaparray( cmap: Colormap ) -> "N x 3 rgb array":
    # only ListedColormap has .colors, this works for both Listed and Linseg
    return cmap( np.linspace( 0, 1, cmap.N )) [:,:3]

def printcmap( cmap: Colormap ):
    print( f"{cmap.name}  len {cmap.N}:" )
    print( cmaparray( cmap ).T, "\n" )
    
#...............................................................................
if __name__ == "__main__":
    np.set_printoptions( precision=2 )
    print( 80 * "▄" )

    cmapname = "YlOrBr"  # Linseg
    # cmapname = "viridis"  # ListedColormap
    nin = 8
    nout = 10
    print( f"params: {cmapname = }  {nin = }  {nout = } \n" )

    cmap = pl.get_cmap( cmapname, nin )  # ListedColormap / LinearSegmentedColormap
    printcmap( cmap )

    sample = cmap.resampled( nout )  # does np.interp ? no dups
    sample.name = "sample"
    printcmap( sample )
```